# Can you send data to a raspberry pi server that is out in the woods?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am making a sort of rover where you control it from your computer and the rover will be outside. I want the computer to send data to the raspberry pi using a server that is on the raspberry pi. Will I be able to do that if the raspberry pi in in the woods?

If not is there anyway I can achieve this goal?

Comment: Depends.  Does your woods have wi-fi repeaters?

Comment: quite often people use 4g/lte hats for that

Comment: I want my rover to work in any place you put it

Answer (score 0):

yeah but you need one of the following network connections:

- cell phone
- sat.
- wifi setup to connect

you could use a small battery (like phone charger to power it for a few days and with a cell phone (battery powered or better plugged if you have power access. I have ducked tapped a pie to a cell phone and a big battery/plugin and set it up in the deep woods. mobile setup

---